# Sending HTTP Response via Java's PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am trying to use a Socket with a PrintWriter to send HTTP Response messages to a normal web browser but from the browser's perspective, it only detected the HTTP response header I sent but could not get the response body despite.

```
String response = "helloworld";
System.out.println("Content is: " + response);

if ((response != null) || (!response.isEmpty)) {
    respCode = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                + "Date: " + getServerTime() + "\r\n"
                + "Connection: Close \r\n"
                + "Server: MyServer v1.0\r\n"
                + "Content-Length: " + response.length() + "\r\n"
                + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
                + "<html><body>" + response + "</body></html>\r\n";
     return respCode;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

And the socket codes

```
public void sendHttpResponse(String input) {
    wr.write(input);
    wr.flush();
}
```

Comment: Content-Length is the length of the whole HTTP body; it must take into account <html><body>…

Comment: It also must take byte encoding into account. HTTP transfers bytes, not characters.